# how to post to facebook wall from android app

Tags: android, facebook

I am using this method for post on facebook but it return the below response

got response:

> {"error":{"message":"(#200) The user hasn't authorized the application
>   to perform this action","type":"OAuthException","code":200}}

how to add permission and where? for post.

```
     public void postOnWall(String msg) {

        Log.d("Tests", "Testing graph API wall post");

         try {

                String response = facebook.request("me");

                Bundle parameters = new Bundle();

                parameters.putString("message", msg);

                parameters.putString("description", "test test test");

                response = facebook.request("me/feed", parameters, "POST");

                Log.d("Tests", "got response: " + response);

                if (response == null || response.equals("") || 
                        response.equals("false")) {
                   Log.v("Error", "Blank response");
               }

         } catch(Exception e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to authorize the user with the `publish_actions` permission. Information and example code can be found in the official docs:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android/v2.3
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android/permissions

Keep in mind that this will only work for users with a role in the App (Admin, Developer, Tester). In order to go public, you need go through a review process with `publish_actions`: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/login

Comment: from where do i authorized a publish_actions permission ?

Comment: you need to implement user login, see the facebook docs links for that

Answer (score 0):

if you haven't done the following things do it.
Go to this link and click on 
"Do you want to make this app and all its live features available to the general public?" and set it to on.
secondly, if you have not given contact email , click on 
https://developers.facebook.com/apps/1585799774985709/settings/" link and provide a contact email.

Comment: please give me the first link for making app and all its live features available to the general public

Comment: that´s just to make the app live, it´s not related to the user authorization